# can't install a go module, using get -u and install

Tags: go

I want to install go-fastping, but when I try using
`go get -u github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping`, this error gets displayed:

```
go: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory.
        'go get' is no longer supported outside a module.
        To build and install a command, use 'go install' with a version,
        like 'go install example.com/cmd@latest'
        For more information, see https://golang.org/doc/go-get-install-deprecation
        or run 'go help get' or 'go help install'.
```

so I changed to install:
`go install github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping`

```
Try 'go install github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping@latest' to install the latest version
```

and after I did changed to: `go install github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping@latest`

it worked but when I try to add it in the code it says that the module is not installed.

Comment: Create a module for your code before executing `go get`.  See the tutorial https://go.dev/doc/code.

Comment: just run `go mod init` that should create the go mod file with necessary data for you then rerun the go get ...

Comment: @Sammy it might be important to add that your suggestion should involve the module name in the command similiar to this: ``go mod init github.com/user/repo``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your project most likely doesn't have a `go.mod` file.

Inside the root of your project run `go mod init <module-name>` to create a module and then you can run `go get -u github.com/tatsushid/go-fastping` to add this dependency to your project.

Comment: I tried forbiddenencoding's suggestion and it worked for me. Sammy, you are probably an older go programer and were caught off guard on how the language was changed. (I was (presumable) in the same boat as you). Here is some reading which may help: https://go.dev/blog/using-go-modules - try the migrating section. Good luck.